# How to interpret the fitted functions in a GAM?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, generalized-additive-model

I don't understand how much I can trust in the fitted functions estimated in a generalized additive model. Look for instance to the plot b.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9tXG.png]

The estimated function appears to be increasing but the variability bands are very large. If I suppose that the true and unknown function must stay inside the variability bands, then the true and unknown function can even be a horizontal straight line.
The questions are:
- can the true and unknown function exceed the variability bands?
- since variability bands are not confidence bands, how much can I trust the fitted function? Are the confidence bands larger or smaller than the variability bands?
Thank you.